# Push values to CSV using JavaScript (Values taken from html5 canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, csv, html5-canvas, export-to-csv

I have a JavaScript code which takes the value from the HTML5 canvas by mousedown(when the mouse button is clicked), mousemove(when the mouse is moved and the mouse is dragged) and mouseup(when the click is released).
The program measures the curve length vs the straight line length and displays them in labels.
What I need is pushing the value of the 3 labels in a CSV file everytime the mouseup event occurs.
I am sharing the code below

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
const sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));
var pathLength = 0;
var distance = 0;

const mouse = {x: 0,  y: 0};
const last_mouse = {x: 0,  y: 0};
const initialPoint  = {x: 0,  y: 0};

function distanceBetween(A, B) {
    const dx = B.x - A.x; 
    const dy = B.y - A.y; 
    return (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
}


/* Drawing on Paint App */
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  initialPoint.x = mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  initialPoint.y = mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  pathLength = 0;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  drawStraightLine()
  canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint);
}, false);

function displayLengths() {
    StraightLineDistance.textContent = "Straight Distance: " + distance.toFixed(0) ;
    CurvedLineDistance.textContent = "Curved Distance: " + pathLength.toFixed(0) ;
    StIndex.textContent ="Straightness Index : " + (distance/pathLength);

}

function onPaint(e) {
  last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
  last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();

  pathLength += distanceBetween(last_mouse, mouse);
  distance = distanceBetween(initialPoint, mouse);
  displayLengths();
};


function drawStraightLine() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF000077";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();

  distance = distanceBetween(initialPoint, mouse);
  displayLengths();  
}
```

HTML file

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="center" id="sketch">
  <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</div>
<label id="StraightLineDistance"></label><br/>
<label id="CurvedLineDistance"></label><br/>
<label id="StIndex"></label>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need a backend language like Node.js or PHP to do that if you want to write to the file system.

Comment: I would be happy if I am helped with a pHp solution

Comment: Ask your question using the PHP tag.